# What does "the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty" mean?

Tags: amazon-s3, jersey, java, grizzly

I'm trying to use JetS3 to access Amazon S3 in an app which also uses Jersey with Grizzly (unsure if that is relevant).  My dev environment is Eclipse on OSX 10.7.3 using JRE version 1.7.0u.jdk.

I've read that it relates to not being able to find a "keystore", whatever that is - but it shouldn't need to use any local keys, I'm already providing it with the authentication information for S3 programmatically.

I don't know if this is an issue with my code, or with my dev environment, can anyone help?

*edit*: I added the following on the command line:

```
- Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.7.0u.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/security/cacerts
```

This file exists, but I'm still seeing the same error :-(

Answer (score 0):

The intersection of Java's  file tree and Apple's packaging system strikes again!

I just solved something similar to this (I think the legacy of a botched beta upgrade). Same error, at least. The situation I found on my disk was that there were symbolic links in my JDK installation instead of actual files (including  cacerts):

```
> ls -lt /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0_30-b12-404.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/security/
total 24
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin     79 Apr  7 15:11 blacklist -> /System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/blacklist
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin     81 Apr  7 15:11 cacerts -> /System/Library/Java/Support/CoreDeploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/cacerts
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  admin     87 Apr  7 15:11 trusted.libraries -> /System/Library/Java/Support/Deploy.bundle/Contents/Home/lib/security/trusted.libraries
```

Unfortunately the linked Deploy.bundles did not exist.

In my case, I was able to look back in Time Machine, and find the deleted bundles and restore them.

You may have some older versions already in place that you could link to. At the least you should be able to look and see if you've got a similar underlying issue.

Sorry it's not a complete solution, but I hope it gets you a little farther down the road.

You could always just get the distribution from Oracle, and pop the cert files in place, though if your installation is missing other items there might be other problems.

On google I found this blog:
http://architecturalatrocities.com/post/19073788679/fixing-the-trustanchors-problem-when-running-openjdk-7

The problem there is the openjdk not including the files, and he recommends linking to the Bundle file that I had to restore in my case.